# Do I need to restart Sphinx after changing MySQL port in sphinx.conf?

Tags: mysql, sphinx

Do I need to restart Sphinx after changing MySQL port in sphinx.conf?

I am running Sphinx 0.9.9-release (r2117).

Answer (score 1):

yes, only by restart it will reload the configuration file.
Btw, 0.9.9 is a very very old version. Grab a newer one from sphinxsearch.com.